# Glissando, fall, and lip bends on trumpet, what are some good exersices?

Tags: technique, brass, trumpet, glissando

I had an artist get recommended to me by another trumpet player, his name is Brandon Ridenour. I just listened to him perform a really clear glissando like the one in Rhapsody in blue. Are there any good exercises to practice to get a glissando like that, and anything about falls and lip bends would be helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming your talking about this:

.  Which is killer playing, hadn't heard him before (I think) and its a great performance.

Its great stuff to have in your bag of tricks (and my skills are not near Brandon's), but its a combination of lip strength/flexibility, and coordination of the half-valving you do to break the natural "stepping" (slotting) of the note as you slide up and down the scale.

On the first part, I'd recommend the "Flexus" book by Laurie Drink and John McNeil.  Its a series of calisthenics for flexibility and range and for me it really built the strength to jump intervals and other more modern techniques.

On the second part, you just have to practice the half valve slides.  Different horns seem to have different "sweet spots" on the valves that allow the slide between notes without so much choking of volume.  Work on just jumping up fifths, octaves, and over time that two octave jump you hear him perform will get within reach.

Should also point out some of those note drops (whole step) can be done without half valving.  The Flexus book has those things also.